# Active Directory and Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, active-directory

I'm currently rewriting a script that is in VB into a Powershell script.

What the script does is search our Active Directory for a user based on the script-users input.

```
Function PromptForName{
    $nameInput = "*"
    $nameInput += Read-Host ("Please enter a full or partial name.")
    $nameInput += "*"
    return $nameInput
}

Function FindUsers{
    param ([string]$n)
    $usersArray = Get-ADUser -f {DisplayName -like $n} | Select-Object Name
    return $usersArray
}
```

This code will print out the correct list of names.  What I then want to do is allow the user to choose one of those names, and have more information about that person.  I'm stuck at allowing the script-user to select one of those names.

How can I prompt for another input; where the box will display a numbered list of all the names that FindUsers gave, and then return a number based on which user they chose?  I'm completely lost.

This is currently how I am trying to do it, although I'm pretty sure it's completely wrong.

```
Function PrintUsers{
    param $a
    [int]$i, $j
    [string]$userList
    $j = 1
    foreach($object in $array){
        $userList += ($j + $array[$i])
        $j++
    }
    return $userList
} 

Function SelectUser{
    param $list
    $user = Read-Host ($list)
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have updated my functions to the following:

```
Function FindUsers{
    param ([string]$n)
    $usersArray = @(Get-ADUser -f {DisplayName -like $n} | Select-Object Name| Format-List)
    return $usersArray
}

Function PrintUsers{
    param ([String[]]$array)
    $i
    for($i = 1; $i -lt $usersArray.length; $i++){
        Write-Host "$i. $($usersArray[$i-1].Name)"
    }
}
```

The output after FindUsers is like this:
Name : xxxxx yyyyy
Name : xxxxx zzzzz
etc.

So the return of $usersArray is printing all that.
I don't want any printing until the PrintUsers function, and I want it to be in a numbered list type format like this:
1. xxxx yyyy
2. xxxx zzzz
etc.

I'm having the most difficult time figuring this out.

Comment: Take a look here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730949.aspx. This can help you to add some gui for the user selection.

Comment: @Christian I want the script-user to be able to enter a number (since the possible users will be a numbered list) and then just hit enter to get the number, having to use a mouse will slow it down.  This script is for helpdesk in IT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# get all users
$usersArray = @(Get-ADUser -f {DisplayName -like $n} )

# create menu
for($i=1; $i -le $usersArray.count; $i++){
    Write-Host "$i. $($usersArray[$i-1].Name)"
}

# prompt for user number
$user = Read-Host Enter the user number to get more info

# display full info for selected user
$usersArray[$user-1] | Format-List *
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  now I find out how to display that info in a window, probably a message box or something

Comment: This line: Write-Host "$i. $($usersArray[$i-1].Name)"
is not working. It should be printing a numbered list of all the users names that it are in that array, correct?

Comment: Yes. Do you have any objects in $usersArray/ If so, do they have a Name property?

Comment: It seems to be working now, but I'm having some weird issues where Get-ADUser does not return some users.  For example if I search for my name the script hangs and does not find me, or if I search for Ryan it will find two Ryan L's, but a search for Ryan L will only return one person.

Comment: Do you get different results when you use ADUC?

Comment: I figured it out.  It was the difference between using -lt and -le, I should have known that.  Anyways, now I'm having trouble getting the users telephone numbers.  $user.telephonenumber will not return anything it seems.

Comment: You need to include the property: Get-ADUser ... -Property telephonenumber

Comment: that works, thanks!  how can I find a list of every AD property?  I want to be able to get all the common phone numbers someone may have; 5 digit, direct dial, etc.

Comment: Got it.  Time to figure out how to use SQL expressions in powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Use Add-Member to add a unique identifier to each user. Let's treat processes as if they're user objects, for the sake of example:

```
$procs = gps;
$procs = $procs | % { $i=0; } {
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -InputObject $_ -Name Number -Value $i -PassThru;
    $i++;
};
$procs | select Number,Name;
$procid = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the number of the process you would like to operate on';
$proc = $procs | ? { $_.Number -eq $procid };
Write-Host -Object ('Operating on proc: {0}' -f $proc.Name);
```

Comment: Use that after I've gotten all the users names?  Sorry, I don't really understand what you're doing.